# How to get struct array (or pointer) that is part of another struct? in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

In the following code:

```
typedef struct 
{
    uint32_t variable_1;
}struct_1;

typedef struct 
{
    uint32_t variable_2;
}struct_2;

typedef struct 
{
    struct_1 struct_1_var;
    struct_2 struct_2_var;
}struct_all;


struct_all variable_t[10];

struct_1* struct_1_var; //how to get this to point to an array of struct_1 that's inside variable_t?
```

Basically, I want to get an struct_1[10] or struct_2[10] that that is part of variable_t[10].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, because there isn't an array of either `struct_1`s or `struct_2`s in `variable_t` to point *to*.  There is an array of elements, *each* of which has a `struct_1` and a `struct_2`.

If you want an array of just one type of the other of the values in `variable_t`, you'll need to copy them out one at a time into a new array.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. Thought that there was a way to do it without one at a time. Thanks!